# Perl get BST (London) Time or any other time

Tags: perl

in Perl
how do I get current London time? GMT has offset with BST 
is it possible to get the TZ offset or the time itself for a different timezone 
from a NY Red Hat Linux machine?

-Thanks much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use DateTime;
say  "UTC:\t\t"      . DateTime->now->iso8601;
say "London time:\t" . DateTime->now->set_time_zone("Europe/London")->iso8601;
```

---

```
UTC:            2011-04-24T17:45:16
London time:    2011-04-24T18:45:16
```

Comment: How is that different from setting `$ENV{TZ}` to "Europe/London"?

Comment: @tchrist, I believe DateTime is thread-safe and the `$ENV{TZ}` method isn't. I suspect they use different source for the tz database. You can perform other functions on the date or timestamp with DateTime. DateTime has many parsers and formatters.

Comment: @tchrist, also, on Windows (and possibly other platforms), setting `$ENV{TZ}` after the program starts doesn't do anything.  Only the initial value matters.

Comment: Your first example isn't local time; it's UTC.

Comment: @cjm: This is also true on AIX under some set-ups. In fact, setting it before the run doesn’t change anything either. See my RC1 AIX report on p5p. Remember “portable” meant that code ran on “both” systems, back when that meant both BSD and SysV? The truth is that after 30 years at it, I still normally run on BSD systems only (OpenBSD and Darwin, to be precise). Getting it to run that weird BSD-SysV combo called Linux is only a little harder, but SysVish Solaris takes work. AIX is sometimes really hard. Anything more alien I do everything possible to avoid. So far, so good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/Modules) modules. They have all sorts of date and time calculation tools, including timezone support.

The [Time Zones](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/FAQ%3A_Time_Zones) FAQ will get you started on common timezone issues.

Answer (score 0):

In standard Perl:

```
% env TZ=Europe/London date
Sun Apr 24 19:51:24 BST 2011

% env TZ=Europe/London perl -le 'print scalar localtime'
Sun Apr 24 19:51:37 2011

% env TZ=Europe/London perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le 'print strftime "%x %X %Z (%z)", localtime'
04/24/11 19:51:52 BST (+0100)
```